# SQLite errors when adding Sample to ListView

Tags: android, sql, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am Designing an App to add blood samples, When I add new sample to the ListView using custom dialog box , following results are displayed in Run. Also, the ListView is not getting updated with Added samples, which I suppose is due to the SQLite issues. I'm Unable to Figure out what changes need to be made to eliminate the errors. Please guide me for the same as I'm new to Android and SqLite programming.

SQLite code

```
package com.example.finalyearprojectbloodanalysis.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.example.finalyearprojectbloodanalysis.model.SampleNameList;
import com.example.finalyearprojectbloodanalysis.model.SampleViewList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Database realated
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ABC.Db";
    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //Table Samples Properties(MainActivity)- Stating Variables
    private static final String TABLE_SAMPLES = "samples";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String COLUMN_SAMPLE = "sampleName";
    private static final String KEY_DATE_CREATED = "date_created";
    private static final String KEY_DATE_MODIFIED = "time_modified";

    //Table View Properties
    private static final String TABLE_VIEW = "views";
    private static final String VIEW_ID = "_view_id";
    private static final String VIEW_NAME = "_view_name";
    private static final String VIEW_SAMPLE = "_view_sample";
    private static final String RBC_COUNT = "_rbc_count";
    private static final String WBC_COUNT = "_wbc_count";
    private static final String TIME_ELAPSED = "_time_elapsed";

    public MyDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Creating Table for Samples in MainActivity
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SAMPLES + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                GENDER + "TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_SAMPLE + "TEXT, " +
                KEY_DATE_CREATED + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_DATE_MODIFIED + "TEXT" +
                ")");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_VIEW + "(" +
                VIEW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                VIEW_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                VIEW_SAMPLE + " TEXT, " +
                RBC_COUNT + " INTEGER, " +
                WBC_COUNT + " INTEGER, " +
                TIME_ELAPSED + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_DATE_CREATED + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_DATE_MODIFIED + " TEXT" +
                ")");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SAMPLES);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_VIEW);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    //Reset/Delete all sample names in Main Activity when we Select Reset Data in Drop down menu
    public void resetSamples() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SAMPLES);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_VIEW);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void clearViews(String sample) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_VIEW + " WHERE " + VIEW_SAMPLE + "=\"" + sample + "\";");
    }

    //Add new row to the database, i.e add a new sample
    public void addSamples(SampleNameList sampleNameList) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_SAMPLE, sampleNameList.get_sampleName());
        values.put(GENDER, sampleNameList.get_gender());
        values.put(KEY_DATE_CREATED, sampleNameList.get_date_created());
        db.insert(TABLE_SAMPLES, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
    //SAMPLE:To Rename Sample Name when Long pressed on sample and to update Date Modified
    public void updateSample(SampleNameList sampleNameList) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_SAMPLE, sampleNameList.get_sampleName_new());
        values.put(KEY_DATE_MODIFIED, sampleNameList.get_date_created());
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.update(TABLE_SAMPLES, values, COLUMN_SAMPLE + "=\"" + sampleNameList.get_sampleName() + "\"", null);
        db.close();
        continueUpdate(sampleNameList);

    }

    //VIEWS: update the views also when Sample is getting updated
    public void continueUpdate(SampleNameList sampleNameList) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(VIEW_SAMPLE, sampleNameList.get_sampleName_new());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.update(TABLE_VIEW, values, VIEW_SAMPLE + "=\"" + sampleNameList.get_sampleName() + "\"", null);
        db.close();

    }

    //SAMPLE: Delete a row of sample from the database when Long pressed
    public void deleteSamples(String sampleName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_SAMPLES + " WHERE " + COLUMN_SAMPLE + "=\"" + sampleName + "\";");
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_VIEW + " WHERE " + VIEW_SAMPLE + "=\"" + sampleName + "\";");
    }


    public int countMaxId(){
        int maxID = 0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_VIEW
                + " ORDER BY " + VIEW_ID + " DESC LIMIT 1;";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
        if (mCount.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                maxID = mCount.getInt(0);
            } while (mCount.moveToNext());
        }
        return maxID;
    }

    // Fetch/Get all Samples from Database to display in ListView in Mainactivity
    //NOTE: Contact class here is SampleNameList
    public List<SampleNameList> getAllSamples () {
        List<SampleNameList> dataList = new ArrayList<SampleNameList>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // SELECT Query
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SAMPLES + " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_ID + " DESC;", null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                SampleNameList sampledata = new SampleNameList();
                sampledata.set_id(cursor.getInt(0));
                sampledata.set_gender(cursor.getString(1));
                sampledata.set_sampleName(cursor.getString(2));
                sampledata.set_date_created(cursor.getString(3));
                sampledata.set_date_modified(cursor.getString(4));
                // Adding all contact to List
                dataList.add(sampledata);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        // return to contact list
        return dataList;
    }
    // Fetch/Get all Samples from Database to display for SearchView in Mainactivity
    //NOTE: Contact class here is SampleNameList
    public ArrayList<SampleNameList> getSearchResult(String search) {
        ArrayList<SampleNameList> dataList = new ArrayList<SampleNameList>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // SELECT Query
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SAMPLES + " WHERE "
                + COLUMN_SAMPLE + " LIKE \"%" + search + "%\""
                + " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_ID + " DESC;", null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                SampleNameList sampledata = new SampleNameList();
                sampledata.set_id(cursor.getInt(0));
                sampledata.set_gender(cursor.getString(1));
                sampledata.set_sampleName(cursor.getString(2));
                sampledata.set_date_created(cursor.getString(3));
                sampledata.set_date_modified(cursor.getString(4));
                // Adding all contact to List
                dataList.add(sampledata);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return to contact list
        return dataList;
    }

}
```

MainActivity Code

```
package com.example.finalyearprojectbloodanalysis;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.finalyearprojectbloodanalysis.Adapters.sampleNameAdapter;
import com.example.finalyearprojectbloodanalysis.database.Contact;
import com.example.finalyearprojectbloodanalysis.database.MyDBHelper;
import com.example.finalyearprojectbloodanalysis.model.SampleNameList;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ListView nameofSamples; //ListView
    public MyDBHelper db; //to use database MyDBHelper
    private sampleNameAdapter data;  // adapter
    //these variables not used till now
    private SampleNameList samplemodel; // custom class for custom layout
    private ArrayList<SampleNameList> searchResult; // array for input search
    private ArrayList<SampleNameList> savedresults; // array for ListView
    SearchView inputSearch;
    //for Add new sample Dialog Box
    private TextView sampleNameinput;
    private TextView genderinput;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        nameofSamples = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sampleList);
        inputSearch = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        inputSearch.clearFocus();
        savedresults = new ArrayList<SampleNameList>();
        showRecord();

        // Search bar action using SearchView
        inputSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                return false ;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                return false;
            }


        });

    }

    //to create action when long pressed on a Sample
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select an Action");
        MenuInflater samplelist_inflater = getMenuInflater();
        samplelist_inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextmenu_listsample, menu);
    }

    //Functionality of Action when Long pressed on a sample
    //rename and delete sample
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        final ArrayList<SampleNameList> mSamplelist = new ArrayList<>(db.getAllSamples());
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            //When Rename is selected from action
            case R.id.rename_id:
                final String oldSample = mSamplelist.get(info.position).get_sampleName();
                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                //Specify Layout height and width of Alert Dialog Box
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                input.setLayoutParams(lp);
                //Alert Dialog box on selecting Rename sample
                androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Rename Sample Name");
                builder.setMessage("Please enter the new Sample Name for " + oldSample + " :");
                builder.setView(input);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        String samplenameEt = input.getText().toString().trim();
                        //To Update Date modified when sample is renamed, getDate code will be found below
                        String currentDate = getDate();
                        String readpath = Contact.getFolderPath(MainActivity.this);
                        String sameTemp = new String();
                        File f = new File(readpath);
                        if (f.exists()) {
                            File file[] = f.listFiles();
                            for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
                                if (Objects.equals(file[i].getName(), samplenameEt)) {
                                    sameTemp = samplenameEt;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //The user is Alerted when user clicks submit with empty field (i.e without entering the New Sample name)
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(samplenameEt)) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Rename didn't occur as Sample Rename Field was empty",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //The user is Alerted to use Unique sample name as previous Renaming name already existed(to avoid confusion with two same sample names)
                        } else if (Objects.equals(sameTemp, samplenameEt)) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The Sample Name was Already existing. Rename with Unique Sample Name ",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // When there is no problem with Renaming, thus process rename successfully
                        } else {
                            File oldFolder = new File(Contact.getFolderPath(MainActivity.this) + File.separator + oldSample);
                            File newFolder = new File(Contact.getFolderPath(MainActivity.this) + File.separator + samplenameEt);
                            boolean success = oldFolder.renameTo(newFolder);
                            if (!newFolder.exists()) {
                                success = newFolder.mkdirs();
                            }
                            //Alert the user that Sample was Named successfully
                            if (success) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Blood smeared image " + samplenameEt +
                                        " is renamed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                db.updateSample(new SampleNameList());
                                showRecord();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to create blood sample bank folder!"
                                        , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                builder.show();//Positive button is Submit
//Negative Button is Cancel
                break;

            //When Delete is selected from action
            case R.id.delete_id:
                String point_to_folder = mSamplelist.get(info.position).get_sampleName();
                // Alert Dialog for final confirmation to delete
                final androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder alert_deletion = new androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alert_deletion.setTitle("ALERT!");
                alert_deletion.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Permanently Delete " + point_to_folder + " ?");
                //Positive Button is Yes- consent to delete
                alert_deletion.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // define folder delete name
                        String point_to_folder = mSamplelist.get(info.position).get_sampleName();
                        File deletefolder = new File(Contact.getFolderPath(MainActivity.this) + File.separator + point_to_folder);
                        // delete folder
                        deleteRecursive(deletefolder);
                        db.deleteSamples(point_to_folder);
                        //show record
                        showRecord();
                    }
                });

                //Negative Button is Cancel
                alert_deletion.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //User alerted that deletion was cancelled
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Delete Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                // show alert for user prompt
                androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog ad = alert_deletion.create();
                ad.show();
                break;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        showRecord();
    }

    public void showRecord() {
        db = new MyDBHelper(this);
        final ArrayList<SampleNameList> samples = new ArrayList<>(db.getAllSamples());
        data = new sampleNameAdapter(this, samples);
        nameofSamples.setAdapter(data);
        nameofSamples.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            //Open ViewList Activity When a Sample row is clicked
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //dataModel = samples.get(position);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(dataModel.get_id()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewList.class);
                String fldrName = samples.get(position).get_sampleName();
                intent.putExtra("_folderName", fldrName);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(nameofSamples);
    }

//part of SearchView
    public void showSearchResults() {
        db = new MyDBHelper(this);
        String search = inputSearch.getQuery().toString().trim();
        final ArrayList<SampleNameList> samples = new ArrayList<>(db.getSearchResult(search));
        data = new sampleNameAdapter(this, samples);
        nameofSamples.setAdapter(data);
        nameofSamples.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //dataModel = mSamples.get(position);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(dataModel.get_id()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewList.class);
                String fldrName = samples.get(position).get_sampleName();
                intent.putExtra("_folderName", fldrName);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(nameofSamples);
    }

    //for delete and reset
    public void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
        if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()) {
            for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()) {
                deleteRecursive(child);
            }
        }
        fileOrDirectory.delete();
    }

    //When user presses Back twice-confirm if user wants to Exit the app
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Do you really want to EXIT?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finishAffinity();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }

    //part of updation of date
    private String getDate() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }




    //Adding Customised ActionBar (Menu) to MainActivity
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menulist, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Adding Functionality to each options of Menu(Actionbar)
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //About Activity in dropdown menu
        if (id == R.id.about) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        //Reset in Dropdown menu
        else if (id == R.id.reset) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage("Do you really want to Permanently Delete all the Sample Names?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            File dir = new File(Contact.getFolderPath(MainActivity.this));
                            deleteRecursive(dir);
                            db.resetSamples();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Reset executed successfully!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            showRecord();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
        }

        //Add New Sample with custom dialog
        //note, for successful dialog UI, use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout
        else if (id == R.id.new_sample) {
            //Functionality of dialog
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alert.getContext();
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogtoaddsample,null);
            view.layout(300,300,300,300);
            EditText sampleNameinput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.samplename_input);
            EditText genderinput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.gender_input);
            Button submit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
            Button cancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
            alert.setView(view);

            //Appearance of dialog
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
            alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogtoaddsample);
            alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            alertDialog.show();

            //when cancel button is clicked
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            //when Submit button is clicked
            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String samplenameEt = sampleNameinput.getText().toString().trim();
                    String genderET = genderinput.getText().toString().trim();
                    String readpath = Contact.getFolderPath(MainActivity.this);
                    String sameGen = new String();
                    String sameTemp = new String();
                    File f = new File(readpath);
                    if (f.exists()) {
                        File file[] = f.listFiles();
                        for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
                            if (Objects.equals(file[i].getName(), samplenameEt)) {
                                sameTemp = samplenameEt;
                                sameGen = genderET;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    String currentDate = getDate();
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(samplenameEt)) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The sample name cannot be empty!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (Objects.equals(sameTemp, samplenameEt)) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The sample name cannot be same as others!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        //**********************
                        File foldersample = new File(Contact.getFolderPath(MainActivity.this) + File.separator + samplenameEt + genderET);
                        boolean success = true;
                        if (!foldersample.exists()) {
                            success = foldersample.mkdirs();
                        }
                        if (success) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Blood sample " + samplenameEt +
                                    " is added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            db.addSamples(new SampleNameList());
                            showRecord();
                            alertDialog.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to create blood sample bank folder!"
                                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }


                }
            });

            return true;
    }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Images

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNYoe.png) Error in Run

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnXTq.png) Emulator display of dialog box in MainActivity on Clicking Add New Sample

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that **gender** column is **not named gender**, instead due to the **lack of a space** it is instead named **gendertext** change

- `GENDER + "TEXT, " +` to `GENDER + " TEXT, " +`
- likewise change `KEY_DATE_MODIFIED + "TEXT" +` to `KEY_DATE_MODIFIED + " TEXT" +`

You will then need to either

- uninstall the App and then rerun

  - (as the `onCreate` method is only run when the database is created, which is once in it's lifetime, uninstalling the App will delete the database).
- or alternatively increase the version number

  - e.g. chnage `private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` to `private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;`
- Note that all existing data stored in the database will be lost.